# Whatsapp share button for web version

Tags: javascript, button, share, whatsapp

I have this script but its only share from mobile version.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", '.mc_whatsapp_btn', function() {
        if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            var text = $(this).attr("data-text");
            var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
            var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
            var whatsapp_url = ".whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
            window.location.href =  whatsapp_url;
        } else {
            alert("Please use an Mobile Device to Share this Status");
        }
    });
});
```

Can anyone modify this?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
```

checks for mobile and if true, the share logic is executed. In the else branch (meaning it's not a mobile) you get an error message. If you want the same to happen in both versions, just omit the `if`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", '.mc_whatsapp_btn', function() {
        //if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            var text = $(this).attr("data-text");
            var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
            var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
            var whatsapp_url = ".whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
            window.location.href =  whatsapp_url;
        //} else {
            //alert("Please use an Mobile Device to Share this Status");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working ..here is full code <a href="javascript:void(0);"
data-text="hi how r you?
"
data-link="xyz"  class="mc_whatsapp_btn">Share</a>

Answer (score 0):

According the WhatsApp docs: https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/?lang=en

To create a link with just a pre-filled message, use https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext

Example: [https://wa.me/?text=I'm%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing`](https://wa.me/?text=I%27m%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing%60)

The result should be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on("click", '.mc_whatsapp_btn', function() {
// this 3 rows will be used for both - desktop and mobile      
    var text = $(this).attr("data-text");
    var url = $(this).attr("data-link");
    var message = encodeURIComponent(text) + " - " + encodeURIComponent(url);
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        var whatsapp_url = ".whatsapp://send?text=" + message;
    } else {
        var whatsapp_url = "https://wa.me/?text=" + message;
    }
    // again for both
    window.location.href =  whatsapp_url;
});
```

});

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0);"
data-text="hi how r you?
"
data-link="xyz"  class="mc_whatsapp_btn">Share</a>
</div>